# Vertical scrollbar is never displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have problem with vertical scrollbar which is never displayed. This is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer 
        BorderThickness="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Padding="20">
        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="360" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Search View -->
            <ContentControl x:Name="SearchPane" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,20" />

            <!-- Detail View -->
            <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" />

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Partially depends on what is around that Scrollviewer...

Comment: Yes, you are right, this view was in stack panel and this was the problem, when I changed it to grid it has started to work as expected.Thx

Comment: You should probably edit the question (put it in a StackPanel), and then add (and accept) an answer with a Grid.